# How does the Fourier transform of a sinc function change when you scale it by 10?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to understanding the purpose of Fourier transforms in its entirety and I am stuck trying to figure out How the Fourier transform of a sinc function change when you scale it by 10.  I assumed that the sinc if you multiply the sinc function by 10 then the height of the sinc function will grow to a height of 10. Because a sinc function in the frequency domain is a box function(filter) in the spatial domain. Any suggestions or corrections?

Comment: For a linear map $T(cf) = cT(f)$ when $c$ is a scalar.

Comment: Well, the Fourier transform is linear, so it plays nicely with scalar multiplication, i.e. $\mathcal{F}\{ cu(x)\} = c \mathcal{F}\{u(x)\}$